# QsharedMemory with no Qt application

Tags: c++, qt, qsharedmemory

I have an application A, and I want to share some information with an application B.
Application A write information each ~150ms.
Application B read information at any times.

I searched and found `QSharedMemory`, which looks great, but the application B will not be developed by my company, so I can't choose the programming langage.

Is `QSharedMemory` a good idea ?
How can I do that ?

Comment: If you've got no control/input into the development of application B, you can write your part in anything you want, but you're generally going to need to provide some type of document or at the very least a structure the memory is read into (if not an API).  Personally I'd use something else like boost, and provide a library that does the reading.  If they were a client, anyway.    That's the long way of saying that at the end of the day, it's bytes in RAM... the reader can implement what they want.  It might not be the best approach though.

Answer (score 0):

`QSharedMemory` is a thin wrapper around named and unnamed platform shared memory. When named, there's simply a file that the other application can memory-map and use from any programming language, as long as said language supports binary buffers.

I do wonder if it wouldn't be easier, though, if you used a pipe for IPC. `QLocalSocket` encapsulates that on Qt's end, and the other side simply uses a native pipe.

Shared memory makes sense only in certain scenarios, like, say, pushing images that may not change all that much between applications - where the cost of pushing the entire image all the time would be prohibitive in the light of small-on-average bandwidth of changes. The image doesn't need to mean a visual image, it may be an industrial process image, etc.

In many cases, shared memory is a premature pseudo-optimization that makes things much harder than necessary, and can, in case of a multitude of communicating processes, become a pessimization - you do pay the cost in virtual memory for each shared memory segment.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to implement a simple server, using local sockets it should be pretty fast in terms of bandwidth and easy to develop. The server will act to store data from A and deliver it to B upon request.

Obviously, it won't work "with no application" in between. Whether you go for shared memory or a local socket, you will need some server code to run at all time to service A and B. If A is running all the time, it can well be a part of it, but it can also be standalone.

It would be preferable to use a local socket, because the API for that is more portable across different programming languages, in that case A and B can be implemented in arbitrary languages and frameworks and communicate at the socket protocol level. With `QSharedMemory` it won't be as portable in your scenario.